# Build a TreeView based on the object obtained by reflection

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection, proxy

It is necessary to display the element, presented in the form as in the picture, in the form of a tree. The object itself is created at compile time.

[image: Object to viewing.]

[image: New Objet to viewing.]
An attempt to make in this form

```
    <TreeView
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding LanguageInformation.Items}">
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LocalizationBrowserViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding LanguageInformation.Items}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
```

Class for presentation

```
public class Element
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<object> Items { get; set; }
    public Element()
    {
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<object>();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Element` class now allows only one level of hierarchy. To support N levels, the `Element` class needs to be changed as below

```cs
public class Element
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Element> Items { get; set; }
    public Element()
    {
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<Element>();

    }
}
```

`TreeView` needs to be replaced with a `ListView` because the screenshot provided in the question contains multiple columns. `TreeView` does not allow multiple columns but a `ListView`.

`ListView` in WPF supports `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. You can refer [HierarchicalDataTemplate in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1) for the implementation.

Comment: Thank. And how can I create a View correctly, taking into account that the object is a Proxy? How can I enter data in the Name field? And here's another updated screenshot.

Comment: And more one moment. I get object with help reflection(type like a object). And this object gets its type when compiled.

Comment: The proxy in your screenshot hold an object instance. You can update value of those properties using reflection.

Comment: Сould you explain how this can be done? At the same time, is it possible to display this object as a tree?

Comment: You can go through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setvalue?view=netcore-3.1 to see reflection samples. Also you have to create a ViewModel collection using reflection to bind the ListView.